# Messy workshop/ideation sessions

Tags: workshop

I'm pretty new to planning and facilitating ideation sessions. I just ran one a couple of weeks ago that was only the second ideation session I ran. It was imperfect, to say the least. We only had time for one crazy 8's exercise, so no time for a second sketch session to elaborate or further generate ideas. We didn't get through the card sort and voting to the team's satisfaction, so we had to continue that in an additional session. But the team is still not satisfied with the decision-making.

An additional challenge I now have is that we had a previous session end without a decision, as well, so now I'm tasked with coming up with a way to wrap this all up and have ideas from both sessions to start wireframing. But we still need to decide what those ideas will be.

My team is frustrated and fatigued, so I want to keep it super simple. I'm wondering what advice anyone might have to keep it simple and help us move forward.

My team also has a very difficult time making decisions and prioritizing. There is often a lot of disagreement about what's important to focus on and some people, in particular, feel very hurt when they ideas are left out, even in the short term.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it belongs to [Project Management SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think this is a valid UX question. @MRL, can you describe the problem that you and your team are trying to solve with ideation workshops? Is it possible that the problem is not yet sufficiently defined?

Comment: I suspect our focus was too broad and that was part of the problem. We had one session to ideate "personalization" (how to personalize our product for users), and one for "gamification" (how we can apply game mechanics to our product either to existing features or by building new features.)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your team needs to take a step back and work on defining goals and the problems that you're trying to solve. You can lead a "let's zoom out" conversation around:

- What shared meaning does personalization have for all of us?
- What problems might personalization solve for our users?
- What business problems might it help us solve?
- What shared meaning does gamification have for all of us?
- What problems might gamification solve?
- What metrics are we being held accountable for that gamification might improve?

When you document all of the problems to be solved (as specifically as possible, outside of the solution space), your next step is to prioritize them. There are several great exercises that can help with this (see [Prioritization Workshops](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/5-ux-workshops/)); picking the top ones prevents "boiling the ocean".

Once you've collectively identified the problems that are worth solving imminently, then you would work on brainstorming their solutions, which may or may not include personalization and gamification.

It's probable, though, that your stakeholders are absolutely married to implementing personalization and gamification, and are not open to other ideas. If that's the case, your next step would be to brainstorm using the frame of "how might we solve each of the problems we mutually identified and prioritized using [personalization/gamification]?" Sketchups could work well here. You might gather everyone again to take 20 minutes to sketch answers to specific questions like:

"How might we use gamification to help our visitors develop a habit of coming to our app every day, so that we can improve our returning visitor traffic by 20%?"

Everyone gets to put 2 stars or dots on their favorite solutions, and hopefully by then you have enough of a direction to move forward with flows and wireframing.

Comment: Thanks for your response! We did you voting for one of the sessions but ran out of time after the second. I'm wondering if it would have helped our team to have a narrower focus. Like instead of having an ideation session to generate ideas of gamifying any aspect of the product--either new or existing--we could have selected which part/experience of the product we want to enhance and had a session to gamify that specific feature or experience.

Comment: Focus definitely helps. Even if you're looking at this as an enhancement, can you still define a problem to solve? For example, gamification in DuoLingo makes the user feel good, but users learn better when they practice every day. The problem it solved was users drifting away.

Comment: In retrospect, that makes a lot of sense and I wish I had thought to lead the team to define a narrower focus. We're in the very early stages of the product design--still haven't released the first version yet. It seems like a more difficult time to think of a focus.... So now that we have these sessions--one with a vote but no next steps decided, and another with no votes at all. Should we just get together for a short session to vote, decide what to move forward with, and just move on? Once we launch and start getting data, we'll have more clear problems to solve. And we can learn from this.

Comment: That could work. You could do a fun "voting with dollars" exercise - there are ways to gamify the gamification brainstorming. :)